# Why Google Firestore C# SDK is incredibly slow at first write?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, console-application

I'm using Google Firestore C# SDK and the first write operation is extremely slow (more than 50 seconds).

Can you help me to figure out what is happening?

Code:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"<path_to_my_auth.json>");
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.CreateAsync("mydatabase").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("scopes/6160673f-214f-46e2-959d-15ffc51655fc/audit").Document();
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data["abc"] = "123";
docRef.CreateAsync(data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out what is happening: the DNS 8.8.8.8 causes the delay. Changing it to any other, the slowness goes away.

The same scenario occurs if I try to generate an Access Token using Google.Apis.Auth C# SDK.